# Can I add an element to an array pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Is it possible to add an element without modifying anything else to an array pointer? Like is I have `int *p = {1, 2, 3, 4};` is there a possible way to add a number, such as `5` so it's equal to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`?

Comment: Please TRY compiling this line first : `int *p = {1, 2, 3, 4};`, then come here and ask your question.

Comment: The code as written won't compile (shouldn't compile).  In C99 or later, you could write `int *p = (int []){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };` to use a compound literal.  G++ will also accept compound literals, but they are not a part of the C++ 2011 standard.

Comment: Are you interested in an answer for C or for C++?  The two languages are very different in some areas, especially in handling of dynamic memory allocation and arrays.  Choosing one or the other language will get you better answers than choosing both because different answers are appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

With plain array it's not possible without reallocation.

I would propose you to use `std::vector`, which internally contains continuos block of memory and resize automatically when you add elements to it. Moreover you can get pointer to the internal array and pass it to the functions expecting C array:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int* pv = &v[0];
```

Comment: This is a good answer for C++; it is not directly an answer for C.  The question should, ideally, not be tagged with both languages.

Answer (score 1):

`int *p = {1,2,3,4}` will not compile anyway. However you can add to an `int*` if you `realloc` the pointer. Code below will do what you want.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_SIZE 4

//Print the array...
void print_array(int*, int);

void print_array(int *p, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
       printf("> %i\n", p[i]);
}


int main() {
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * DEFAULT_SIZE);
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    memcpy(p, array, sizeof(int) * DEFAULT_SIZE);

    printf("Array...\n");
    print_array(array, DEFAULT_SIZE);

    //Realloc and insert 5
    p = realloc(p, sizeof(int)*(DEFAULT_SIZE + 1));
    p[DEFAULT_SIZE] = 5;

    printf("Modified array...\n");
    print_array(p, DEFAULT_SIZE+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add an element to an array in C, you need to firstly define an array, not a pointer (and make it sufficiently large):

```
int arr[ 5 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

... and then do this:

```
arr[ 4 ] = 5;
```

**Remark:** Pointers and arrays are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: What the OP is actually doing is writing bad syntax. There's no such thing as "a literal of integers".

Comment: @JimBalter, would it not be the equivalent of double quote initialization syntax with the actual corresponding ascii value? That's where I made my assumption from (and C99, not C++).